# Owin Startup Detection

Tags: owin

I developed an application with Owin Startup class. When i am running the OwinHost.exe, it shows `No Assembly found containing OwinStartupAttribute`.

But I defined the assembly in my startup class as:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OwinDemo.BrandStartup))]
```

I also defined appSettings in the Web.Config file as:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="OwinDemo.Startup, OwinDemo"/>
```

Comment: Are you running the Owinhost.exe in the application folder? Here is a detailed tutorial on OWIN startup detection. Can you check if this is helpful? http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: And with the present settings where you have a different Startup class in attribute and config (BrandStartup in attribute and Startup in appSetting), config is expected to win. Can you check if you have a class named OwinDemo.Startup in the OwinDemo assembly?

Comment: @Praburaj Thanks for the reply. Actually I had developed my application by the help of that article. I have my startup class in my application. I have multiple startup classes and i want to start my application with my original startup class. But same error coming.

Comment: Yes, I am running the OwinHost.exe by the application folder.

Comment: If you have multiple startup classes, can you provide a friendly name for each of those and start the application with the friendly name? For example your above OwinStartup attribute can take in a friendly name. Then you can simply put the friendly name in the appSetting instead of the class name. Or you can also pass in the friendly name in the Owinhost.exe command parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Project-> right click  add new item.

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this the correct answer?  I'm trying to distinguish between what this answer is suggesting and the OwinStartup attribute that the asker already said he used on his startup class.