# Not getting Startup.Auth file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am trying to install steam login, for my website, BUT after i have done the installation in nuget package manager console, with the following install code: `Install-Package Owin.Security.Providers.Steam` I am missing my `Startup.Auth.cs`. What am i doing wrong? 
The project is started without "Individual User Accounts".

Comment: What version of MVC?

Comment: @JamesP newVersion="5.2.3.0"

Answer (score 6):

The `Startup.Auth.cs` file should be in your `App_Start` Folder. Just create a default MVC web application with `Individual User Accounts` selected as the Authentication type under `Change Authentication` option to see how its implemented.

For reference:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
using Owin.Security.Providers.Steam;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //other Config

            app.UseSteamAuthentication("your API key");
        }
    }
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079060/steam-openid-in-mvc-application) for reference on how to add the Steam login button.

**Edit**:
Also see [here](http://httpjunkie.com/2013/311/adding-mvc-5-identity-to-an-existing-project/) for [Adding MVC 5 Identity to our Existing Project.](http://httpjunkie.com/2013/311/adding-mvc-5-identity-to-an-existing-project/)

You may need to add startup.cs to root of your project:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the problem is that i do not want it to be with Individual User Accounts. Since i do not need 80% of what they are giving me.

Comment: Ok, I understand but you will still need the `Owin Startup & configure` files above - did you try with just adding the two files above?

Comment: Also see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028311/owin-startup-detection - And here http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection